# PSR-1 2.3 Side Effects Rule

Tags: php, coding-style, side-effects

I have a question Regarding PHP Basic Coding Standards PSR1.
PSR 1 Rule 2.3 states:

> ### Rule 2.3 Side Effects
>
> A file SHOULD declare new symbols (classes, functions, constants,
>   etc.) and cause no other side effects, or it SHOULD execute logic with side
>   effects, but SHOULD NOT do both.
>
> The phrase "side effects" means execution of logic not directly related to
>   declaring classes, functions, constants, etc., *merely from including the
>       file*.
>
> "Side effects" include but are not limited to: generating output, explicit
>   use of 'require' or 'include', connecting to external services, modifying ini
>   settings, emitting errors or exceptions, modifying global or static variables,
>   reading from or writing to a file, and so on.

Can someone give me an argument that supports use of this rule? 
Or, explain the benefit of this rule, and why it is important or a good idea to implement.
This will help me support full implementation of PSR 1 and make a good case.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The idea is that when a class is auto-loaded, the state of the application should not change.
Any state-modifying code (code that actually executes) should be in a different set of files.

This makes it predictable and forces you to keep your logic in class methods, and implicit.

Remember that coding standards exist so people code in a similar style. The benefit in adopting a coding standard is that your codebase is self-consistent and consistent with other projects following the rules.

PSR-1 largely follows what everybody was already doing. If you feel the need to execute logic in the same place where a class is defined, there is very likely a better place or approach.

Lastly.. don't adopt PSR-1 for the sake of. If you have a valid reason to not follow the rules in certain spots, break the rules. They're not laws. Common sense reigns supreme.

Source: I'm one of the contributers of that document.

Comment: Is making the code testable to test one practical reason to do this? i.e. it is easier to load and test a function / class if there is nothing else going on in the file that declares the function / class.

Comment: @michaelmcandrew Yea that could be a reason. I think I'd generally expect a class auto-loading to not have any side-effects other than new symbols to be defined.