# yii2 user role becomes 0 when message is sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I've got yii2 site with chat function. Each user role has their own chat block (admins have their messages in blue blocks, users have user messages in blue blocks etc.). Problem is when message is sent with ajax, user role becomes 0 (user role), and for admins and organisations chat looks like chat for regular user.
Here is php code for admin messages:

```
use common\models\Order;
$cure = $user->role;
    if($messages=$order->ordermessages)
    {
        foreach ($messages as $message)
        { 
                if($cure == \common\models\Account::ROLE_ADMIN){
                if($message->author_id==$order->client_id) //user's message
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="chat_item">
                        <div class="chat_ava"></div>
                        <div class="chat_gray">
                            <span class="ch_autor">Заказчик</span>
                            <?php echo $message->message?><br><?php if($message->img)echo'
                          <div><a class="gs_img fancybox" data-fancybox="gall" href="'.$message->img.'"><img src="'.$message->img.'" alt=""></a></div>';?>
                            <div class="cb_time"><?php echo date('d.m.Y H:i',$message->date)?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                 if($message->author_id==71) // admin's message
                {
                    ?>
                        <div class="chat_item">
                        <div class="chat_blue">
                            <?php echo $message->message?><br><?php if($message->img)echo'
                          <div><a class="gs_img fancybox" data-fancybox="gall" href="'.$message->img.'"><img src="'.$message->img.'" alt=""></a></div>';?>
                            <div class="cb_time"><?php echo date('d.m.Y H:i',$message->date)?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <?php
                }
                
                if($message->author_id==87) // organisation's message
                {
                    ?>
                     <div class="chat_item">
                        <div class="chat_org"></div>
                        <div class="chat_gray">
                            <span class="ch_autor">Организация</span>
                            <?php echo $message->message?><br><?php if($message->img)echo'
                          <div><a class="gs_img fancybox" data-fancybox="gall" href="'.$message->img.'"><img src="'.$message->img.'" alt=""></a></div>';?>
                            <div class="cb_time"><?php echo date('d.m.Y H:i',$message->date)?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
        }
```

Here is the ajax script:

```
    $(document).on('submit','.add_worker_form2', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".chat_frame").scrollTop($(".chat_frame")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 400);

        var id=$(this).data('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        var $yiiform = $(this);    // отправляем данные на сервер
        $.ajax({
                type: $yiiform.attr('method'),
                url: $yiiform.attr('action'),
                data: new FormData($yiiform[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
            }
        )
            .done(function(data) {

                    if($('.ch_'+id).length)
                        $('.ch_'+id).remove();
                    $('body').append(data);
                    $('.ch_'+id).toggleClass('opened');
            })
            .fail(function () {
                // не удалось выполнить запрос к серверу
            })
        return false; // отменяем отправку данных формы
    })
```

}
}

I know that after message is sent - chat

Comment: Where is `$message` being populated? I'm not seeing any reference in the ajax call to a `message` value, so I'm assuming this value is being assigned somewhere in the PHP outside of what we're seeing here. Are you sure that it contains what you think it contains? What do you get back if you put a `var_dump($message)` at the top of the top of the example you're showing here? This feels like an empty-string-cast-to-int problem, but I could be way off.

Comment: One other very small nitipick: You probably want to assign your "magic numbers" (71, 87) to constants so that they're easier to change in the future.

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus I added $message in php code

Comment: that makes sense. Can you show that part of the PHP script?

Comment: I've showed it. it's `if($messages=$order->ordermessages){` by `I added $message in php code` I meant that I've added it to question. It already was in my php code on site

Comment: oh yes -- sorry I missed that. Now we have the same issue with `$order` :-)

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus `$order` is from module `use common\models\Order;`. I've included it at the very beginning

Comment: I see. So the definition of the `$order` variable is a side effect of the inclusion of the class definition? That's generally the type of setup you want to avoid -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298795/psr-1-2-3-side-effects-rule -- but maybe it's a legacy thing that came with the Yii ecosystem. (I don't know much about Yii.) In any case, I think we've reached the limits of my knowledge. Hopefully someone with more knowledge of Yii can help you out. Good luck!

Comment: Add sample data of `$order` and `$message` variables. Active Record sample will work.